# php xml_encode set attribute to specific tag name

Tags: php, arrays, json, xml, domdocument

I xml_encode my array using this code.

```
public function xml_encode($mixed, $domElement=null, $DOMDocument=null) {
    if (is_null($DOMDocument)) {
        $DOMDocument =new DOMDocument;
        $DOMDocument->formatOutput = true;
        $this->xml_encode($mixed, $DOMDocument, $DOMDocument);
        echo $DOMDocument->saveXML();
    }
    else {
        // To cope with embedded objects 
        if (is_object($mixed)) {
          $mixed = get_object_vars($mixed);
        }
        if (is_array($mixed)) {
            foreach ($mixed as $index => $mixedElement) {
                if (is_int($index)) {
                    if ($index === 0) {
                        $node = $domElement;
                    }
                    else {
                        $node = $DOMDocument->createElement($domElement->tagName);
                        $domElement->parentNode->appendChild($node);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $plural = $DOMDocument->createElement($index);
                    $domElement->appendChild($plural);
                    $node = $plural;
                    if (!(rtrim($index, 's') === $index)) {
                        $singular = $DOMDocument->createElement(rtrim($index, 's'));
                        $plural->appendChild($singular);
                        $node = $singular;
                    }
                }

                $this->xml_encode($mixedElement, $node, $DOMDocument);
            }
        }
        else {
            $mixed = is_bool($mixed) ? ($mixed ? 'true' : 'false') : $mixed;
            $domElement->appendChild($DOMDocument->createTextNode($mixed));
        }
    }
}
```

https://www.darklaunch.com/2009/05/23/php-xml-encode-using-domdocument-convert-array-to-xml-json-encode

and it works well. Now, I want to set an attribute to a specific tag.

Let's say for example this is my xml.

```
<book>
     <title>PHP Programming</title>
     <description>Learn how to code in PHP</description>
</book>
```

I want to set an attribute to **title** tag and make it

```
<title name=attributeValue>
       PHP Programming
</title>
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to share with you guys, if others are also having a problem like this. 
I have just solved my problem. 
In this part

```
if (is_null($DOMDocument)) {
        $DOMDocument =new DOMDocument;
        $DOMDocument->formatOutput = true;
        $this->xml_encode($mixed, $DOMDocument, $DOMDocument);
        //echo $DOMDocument->saveXML();
        return $DOMDocument;
    }
```

I returned the $DOMDocument. Then I did this

```
$xml = $this->xml_encode($data);
     $xmlstring = $xml->saveXML();
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadXML($xmlstring);

        foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('title') as $item) {
            $item->setAttribute('name', 'attributeValue');
            echo $dom->saveXML();
        }
```

and I got a correct result.